# Validate jaxws soap request against schema inside wsdl:types

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, xml-validation

I'm wanting to validate a soap request against the schema inside this wsdl.

```
<wsdl:types >
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://ws.thecompany.com/FormSubmissionService20100824" 
                xmlns:request="http://xmlschema.thecompany.com/generic/FormHeader20100824" xmlns:response="http://xmlschema.thecompany.com/generic/FormResponse20100824">

        <xsd:import namespace="http://xmlschema.thecompany.com/generic/FormHeader20100824" schemaLocation="../schema/generic/FormHeader20100824.xsd"/>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://xmlschema.thecompany.com/generic/FormResponse20100824" schemaLocation="../schema/generic/FormResponse20100824.xsd"/>

        <xsd:element name="submitFormRequest" type="request:FormHeader"/>
        <xsd:element name="submitFormResponse" type="response:FormResponse"/>

        </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>

<!-- Message Definition -->
<wsdl:message name="submitFormRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="thecomp:submitFormRequest" name="request" />
</wsdl:message>
```

Loading a `javax.xml.validation.Validator` for the schema validating against a `< thecomp:submitFormRequest>` element doesn't work, neither does attempting to load the wsdl as the schema.

Ideas please?
 (using jax-ws, was7)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extracted the request/response into its own schema file:

```
    <wsdl:types > 
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://ws.acc.co.nz/ACCFormSubmissionService20100824" 
                schemaLocation="../schema/ws/ACCFormSubmissionService20100824.xsd" />
    </xsd:schema>               
</wsdl:types>
```

Validating against the new schema namespace/xsd works as required.